# Serialize and Deserialize an array of custom object using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an array of below object, now i want to serialize and deserialize this using jQuery.

Is there any way of doing this.

```
var Filter = function(columnIndex, filterColumnName, operator, filterColumnValue) {
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
        this.filterColumnName = filterColumnName;
        this.operator = operator;
        this.filterColumnValue = filterColumnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,i figure it out it can done simply by using below two methods

Serialize

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(Filter);
```

De-Serialize

```
var javascriptObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```